# Python3.6 - Cannot import gensim in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, gensim

I use Python 3.6.3rc1. I get following message after executing my python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from train import train
  File "C:\path\train.py", line 2, in <module>
    import dataUtils
  File "C:\path\dataUtils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import gensim
ImportError: No module named gensim
```

But gensim is already installed. Command `pip3 freeze` gives following list:

```
bleach==1.5.0
boto==2.48.0
bz2file==0.98
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
gensim==3.0.1
html5lib==0.9999999
idna==2.6
jieba==0.39
Markdown==2.6.9
numpy==1.13.3+mkl
protobuf==3.4.0
requests==2.18.4
scipy==0.19.1
six==1.11.0
smart-open==1.5.3
tensorflow==1.3.0
tensorflow-tensorboard==0.1.7
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

When I imported KeyedVectors from gensim.models (`from gensim.models import KeyedVectors`) in another script, it worked.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

this might be caused by `pip3` using another python executable than your script.

try debugging by inserting a `import sys; print(sys.path)` and check if it contains any of your `pip3` paths...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I removed following line at the beginning of executable file and it solved problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```